# Expand / collapse a folder in kendo treeView is very slow when the tree is big

Tags: kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I am creating a tree with kendo treeView like this:

```
  const treeViewOptions: kendo.ui.TreeViewOptions = {
        dataBound: (e: kendo.ui.TreeViewDataBoundEvent): void => {
            // Add class to the treeItem that is a folder to distiguish between leaf and folder.
            const treeItem = $(this.treeViewElementId + ' .k-item:has(.k-group)');

            if (treeItem.length > 0) {
                treeItem.addClass("folder-tree-item");
            }
        },

        dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            sort: { field: "text", dir: "asc" },
            transport: {
                read: (options: kendo.data.DataSourceTransportOptions) => { this.onLoadFolder(options); }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                },
            }
        }),

        dataSpriteCssClassField: "iconClass",

        template:

            // Text - I have a template here.


        // Make all nodes load automatically before expanding
        loadOnDemand: false,

        // Apply scrolling when item focus changes
        navigate: (e) => { this.onNavigate(e); },}
```

When I expand or collapse a node this is take a lot of time until the folder is open / close..

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was already discussed in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752279/kendo-treeview-expanding-big-tree-issue), basically you need to either update kendo ui or follow the steps given in the answer to the question.

Hope this helps you :)